# Spring Boot: How can I reset the entity ID back to 0 every time I make Delete request with client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have created a server using Java Spring Boot and I made a delete request that deletes all entries in a repository. I tried adding it back and the ID incremented instead of starting back to 0.

```
@DeleteMapping("/donors")
public String deleteAllDOnors() {
    return donorService.deleteAllDonors();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

Edit. I tried this so far in a service class:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

In the same class:

```
public String deleteAllDonors() {
    entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("ALTER TABLE SomeTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
            .executeUpdate();
    donorRepository.deleteAll();
    return "All donors removed!";
}
```

I get a

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1668) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what persistence layer you are using but following is an example of JPA on how you can reset it

```
entityManager
    .createNativeQuery("ALTER TABLE SomeTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I apologize in advance but I'm just recently learning. And could you link me to what a persistent layer is so I could read on it and give you more information? And where do I exactly put this? I tried placing it in services by putting a "@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;" but I just got an error. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: No worries. So the question is how are you connecting to DB from Spring Boot app? Are you using Spring-data, Spring-data- JPA, JPA -hibernate etc?

Comment: I'm using spring-data-JPA. I'm connecting it to MySQL, too, if that information helps.

Comment: Updated my post to provide more details.

Comment: Everything you did above is correct just add the @Transactional to your class for example


@ Transactional
Public yourClass {


}

Comment: Damn, I added it but the same error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

We could annotate the test class with the @DirtiesContext annotation and set the value of its classMode attribute to DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD. This would fix our problem because our application creates a new in-memory database when its application context is loaded, and the @DirtiesContext annotation ensures that each test method uses a new application context.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

Comment: But this isn't a question about test classes.